# Error (Assertion `args[3]->IsInt32()' failed) using a simple create in Prismajs

Tags: node.js, prisma

In a Express + Nodejs api

**client.ts (to instance the prisma object)**

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

// add prisma to the NodeJS global type
interface CustomNodeJsGlobal extends NodeJS.Global {
    prisma: PrismaClient;
}

// Prevent multiple instances of Prisma Client in development
declare const global: CustomNodeJsGlobal;

const prisma = global.prisma || new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') global.prisma = prisma;

export default prisma;
```

**post.ts (where I get the error)**

```js
// createPost Function
const createPost = async (req: FeedRequest, res: Response): Promise<void | Response> => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            message: 'Validation fail, entered data is incorrect',
            errors: errors.array(),
        });
    }

    const { title, content, creator } = req.body;

    const post = await prisma.posts.create({
        data: {
            title,
            content,
            creator,
        },
    });

    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Post created successfully!',
        post: post,
    });
};
```

#### Error when I try to use the endpoint to create a post

```sh
node/v16.0.0/bin/node[14161]: ../src/node_http_parser.cc:567:static void node::{anonymous}::Parser::Initialize(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args[3]->IsInt32()' failed.
1: 0xb12b00 node::Abort() [/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node]
2: 0xb12b7e  [/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node]
3: 0xb2a282  [/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node]
4: 0xd5f70b  [/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node]
5: 0xd60bac  [/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node]
6: 0xd61226 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node]
[Node]  7: 0x160c579  [/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node]
```

If I remove the `const post = await prisma.posts.create...` part, all work okay. I really not sure what is happening here

Answer (score 3):

The current prisma version (2.21.2) is not compatible yet with the current last version (16) of nodejs. Downgrade temporary to the last LTS of nodejs fix the problem.

Comment: prisma@2.28.0 still gives the same issue. I can confirm that node@14.7.4 works with this prisma version and that node@16.4.2 did not